# Is the noun phrase 'side lengths to the nearest tenth' grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, mathematics, adjective-phrases

Here is a sentence extracted from the entire question sentences, one from [this exercise page on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/trig-with-general-triangles/law-of-sines/e/law_of_sines).

> The following figure shows △ABC with side lengths to the nearest tenth.

I thought the above sentence was missing the word 'rounded', so that should have been:

> The following figure shows △ABC with side lengths **rounded** to the nearest tenth.

Is the sentence from Khan Academy natural and grammatically correct, or my guess is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their version is completely understandable and unambiguous to me.
Some word has been elided...

*shown/listed/rounded to the nearest tenth*

bu there's no difficulty in supplying it. The units after "tenth" are also omitted.

Your version is fine too.